# Find edges of a piecewise curve

Tags: piecewise

I have a continuous function `f[x]`, and I want to calculate the coordinates of the discontinuities in `Round[f[x]]`. My code needs to do this computation many thousands of times, so very efficient code is appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain further? Round[x] has discontinuities at each integer value of x. So Round[f[x]] would have discontinuities every time f[x] is an integer. If this what you are looking for? And what does this have to do with edges of a piecewise curve?

Comment: Indeed, this is what I am looking for! Sorry if my question is not clear: I want to find where Round[f[x]] changes. Perhaps piecewise is not the correct terminology.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what kind of function f[x] is? Or provide a simple example?

Comment: f[x] is a continuous function on some finite interval, say x in [0,1]. That is all that's known. For a simple example, consider ```a/(1 + b x) Sin[c x]``` for a,b,c >1

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you can expect. Consider (3/2) Sin[1/x] on [0,1]. This has an infinite number of such points.

Comment: I don't think Sin[1/x] is continuous on the closed interval [0,1], since it is not defined at x = 0. Anyway, to be clear, I'm interested in functions with only a finite set of such points, although the finite number is not known.